# How to tell which NSTextField was edited?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview, undo

My `NSDocument` subclass adopts `NSTextFieldDelegate`. The document window contains several `NSTextField` instances (all setup as outlets of the document class). When the user edits a text field, I want my document to be notified. But all the methods in the NSTextFieldDelegate protocol are inherited from NSTextViewDelegate and hence pass NSText* instances in their parameters, **NOT** NSTextField instances. The same applies to the notification:

```
- (void) controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification*) notification
```

So, How do I find out **which** of the many NSTextField instances is being edited?

**NOTE**

I need to register undos properly, using the document's undo manager. I tried implementing
- (NSUndoManager *)undoManagerForTextView:(NSTextView *)aTextView
but this seems to only work with `NSTextView`s, **NOT** `NSTextField`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a reference to your `NSTextField` as `[notification object]`.  From the documentation for `NSControlTextDidChangeNotification`:

> The notification object is the NSControl object posting the
>   notification.

The actual control subclass will be your `NSTextField`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it! I was checking the notification's userInfo only, didn't think of that!